# Output null string from API

Tags: php

So I'm using the following array to pass in `$record params` , but I'm getting errors when a particular return from the API is null.

Here is the array:

```
$office->load([
    'post_title' => $record->office,
    'location_id' => $record->location_id,
    'location' => $record->location,
    'business_unit' => $record->business_unit,
    'type_id' => $record->type_id,
    'brand_id' => $record->brand_id,
]);
```

My `$record->brand_id` is being returned as null and it crashes my whole script, is there a way that I can output null as a string and wrap the $record->brand_id in something?

Update:

I ended up configuring the needed `brand_id` as `$record->brand_id ?? $default_value` which worked great!

Comment: (brand id is not empty) ? put brand id : put an empty string

Comment: There isn't a single clue about what is `$office`, where does `$record` come from, what API, whose API, where is it running... The only thing I could suggest is that if a value should not be null, you could use an if to check if it's null... `$record->brand_id!==null?$record->brand_id:''`.

Comment: is this working for you ? `((isset($record->brand_id))?$record->brand_id:"")`

Comment: Can you precise your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which values may be `null` and have no impact on API output you can try operators checking null values, like `null coalescing operator (??)`.

```
$default_value = 'default';

$office->load([
    'post_title' => $record->office,
    'location_id' => $record->location_id,
    'location' => $record->location,
    'business_unit' => $record->business_unit,
    'type_id' => $record->type_id,
    'brand_id' => $record->brand_id ?? $default,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Tajni, this worked so well! Could you please upvote my answer?